# What sort of monster is this?

Tags: javascript

I came across some javascript that looked like this, and I wondered what is was.  It functions like a singleton class defined and instanced inside of a variable declaration.  What do I call this type of construction?

```
<script>
    var abacus=
    {
        runningSum:0
        ,addSum:function(i){
            this.runningSum += i;
            return this.runningSum;
        }
        ,subtractSum:function(i){
            this.runningSum -= i;
            return this.runningSum;
        }
    }
    console.log(abacus.addSum(3));
    console.log(abacus.subtractSum(2));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a monster. It's an anonymous object constructor (literal) assigned to the variable abacus. It has three properties: runningSum, addSum, and subtractSum. addSum and subtractSum are assigned anonymous functions.

Comment: A loveable monster, but a monster none the less :-)

Answer (score 5):

Its just an object literal and its a perfectly reasonable way to define "singletons". I don't think there is a special name for it.

The only strange thing is the indentation - most people would write it more like this:

```
var abacus = {
    runningSum: 0,
    addSum: function(i){
        this.runningSum += i;
        return this.runningSum;
    },
    subtractSum: function(i){
        this.runningSum -= i;
        return this.runningSum;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called an object literal.

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/